# jQuery Hover Effects: Having One Div Disappear And Another Div Appear

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, jquery-animate

I wrote a question earlier, however, I forgot to ask the second part.

My original question asked for help with a hover animation (which worked wonderful); however, when one div disappears I need another one to appear in its place.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div id="beach2"></div>
        <div class="layer3"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
               <div class="layer4">
                <div class="magnifyingGlass"></div>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/magnify.png" class="img-responsive" id="magnify" alt="Magnifying Glass" /></a>
               </div>
               <div class="layer5">
               <div class="label">
                        <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                        <p class="title2">amet consetetur sadipscing eltir</p>
                </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

I need '.layer3' to disappear and '.layer4' and '.layer5' to appear on hover.

CSS:

```
.layer3{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -340px;
    background-color: rgba(226, 151, 145, 0.5);
}

.wrapper{
    display: none;
}

#magnify{
    margin-top: -35px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.magnifyingGlass{
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    z-index: 999;
}

.layer4{
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, .5);
    margin: -210px 20px 0 0;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -205px;
}

.label{
    height: 65px;
    width: 99%;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.layer5{
    height: 75px;   
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, .5);
    margin-top: -75px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    position: relative;
}


.title{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

#title2{
    color: #087253;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.layer3').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity:'0'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
        }
    );

    $('.wrapper').mouseover(
        function(){
            $(this).show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fixe the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use CSS

```
.layer3, .wrapper { transition: opacity 1s }
.layer3:hover, .layer3:not(:hover) + .wrapper { opacity: 0 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unU2q/).

The `+` means *next child*, while the `:not()` evaluates to true when the condition inside is false, in this case when `.layer3` is **not hovered**.

Comment: How do you write that in syntax?

Comment: Thanks bjb568; however, Andreas' solution is closer to what I was working toward.

Comment: @bjb568 What do you mean by abuse of javascript? Why is it better using pure CSS over jQuery in this case? (Genuinly asking)

Comment: @Andreas The simplest answer is that **CSS was made for this**. Because of that, there are all kinds of side effects to misuse. Using JS (further, a library on top of it) will slow down the transition so it appears rough. Using jQuery also requires considerably more code, thus it's harder to debug and maintain. Of course, using javascript requires users to have javascript enabled too.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just add the actions inside the hover-function?
If this is what you want to achieve, then you should get a better understanding of [jQuery and it's selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.layer3').hover(
        function(){
            $(".layer4, .layer5").show(); // Added this
            $(this).animate({opacity:'0'});
        },
        function(){
            $(".layer4, .layer5").hide(); // And this
            $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
        }
    );

    $('.wrapper').mouseover(
        function(){
            $(this).show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Andreas yours is on the write track; however, I need it to spread over four different divs. ex: 'beach1', 'beach2', 'beach3', 'beach4'.

Comment: Going to bed now. I will write an extensive article on this tomorrow if you haven't got an answer by then :)